# how to upload two apk files with diff API levels of a single android application

Tags: android, google-play

My app has two apk file, one with API level 7-9 and other with 10-17. Previously I used to switch back to the old design of developer console to upload two apks of a single app but Old Developer Console has been deprecated from April 15 2013:( Please guide me as to how do I upload multiple apk files of a single application.

Thanks in advance

Comment: http://developer.android.com/google/play/publishing/multiple-apks.html. Check the link

Comment: @Raghunandan: I couldn find step by step procedure to upload both apk files. In the link which u provided, multiple apks using extension files is given. This is not what I want

Answer (score 0):

[image]

this is what appears when i try to upload second apk

Comment: have you uploaded it in advanced mode? have you read the documents thoroughly? that should answer all of your questions

Comment: @StinePike : yes i ve uploaded in advanced mode only.

Comment: @StinePike: FYI advanced mode is slightly visible in the screenshot

Comment: Nt sure why you are facing this because if you follow the procedure you can upload both apk .. here is another tutorial to do so .. http://developer.sonymobile.com/2011/10/11/use-the-multiple-apk-support-in-android-market/

Comment: @StinePike : Thanku for ur replies Stine but the tutorial uses the old developer console design and i used to follow the same procedure. The old design is now deprecated :(

Answer (score 0):

I spent a couple of hours trying to figure this out, you must do it in **Advanced mode** else it wont work.